# Mysql query - Group By one field and ordering by another

Tags: mysql, sql

I am having a bit of trouble with a MySQL query and was hoping to get some help. The query seems fairly simple but I can't seem to get it right.

I have a table named login with the fields:
login_id PK
member_id FK from a members table
stamp - a UNIX timestamp, when the member logged in

A record is inserted into this table each time a member logs in.

All I want to do is get each member_id and the most recent login, that is the highest stamp value. I tried:

```
SELECT member_id,FROM_UNIXTIME(stamp) as log_time 
FROM `logins` 
WHERE member_id = 27
GROUP BY member_id
ORDER BY stamp DESC
```

But the result was not what I was looking for, I just got the first record of each member login.

If anyone could help with this it would be very much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: I never really fully understood why MySQL allows aggregation functions without a group by clause (also the other way around: referencing a column not in a group by clause without aggregation function). This is very misleading...

Comment: Why not use [the now function](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_now.asp) in MySQL instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
SELECT member_id, FROM_UNIXTIME(MAX(stamp)) AS log_time
FROM logins
GROUP BY member_id
ORDER BY stamp DESC
```

each member id, along with the time of the most recent login, sorted by everyone's login time descending (most recent first).

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT member_id, max(stamp) FROM `logins` GROUP BY member_id
```

Answer (score 3):

Try replacing stamp in your field list with MAX(stamp)

Answer (score 1):

And if you like to get the recent time of a particlar user you do not need even grouping, just use:

```
SELECT MAX(stamp) FROM logins WHERE member_id = 27
```